# #include directories are not recognized, My tutor cant resolve it

Tags: c++, include, directory

I have an issue with my #include directories. I am creating a game project called Project_2_ within the same solution I have a project called Library which holds to its name. 
I have created a few .h and .cpp files in my Project_2_:
Asteroid h /.cpp
Serialiser h / .cpp
GameManager h /.cpp 
Main h / cpp

Now my problem is that some of the file will accept include directories and others will not. GameManager.h will only accept Serialiser.h but not Asteroid.h or any of the library files.
Serialiser.h will only accept Project_2_ files and Asteroid.h will accept any file I include.
standard windows files are accepted in all. 
So here is what my tutor suggested and it has not worked so far:

checked that the library is linked to the project...
changed the additional include directory in GameManager.h's properties from "C/file/file/Library" to "..Library"....
I have tried creating new projects and new files making sure that they are "empty projects"....
quintuple checked all my spellings....
adjusted the path of the Asteroid.h /.cpp directories because they were in the Library (mistake I guess?)

I have sent my project to my tutor on several occasions and he is able to compile my programme on his machine.
So I think that's a lot of the basic stuff covered. Is it something that could be specific to my computer? I'm running 64 bit windows 7 (laptop)

Thanks in advance,
 Dan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First some things you have to make sure that you have.

All your different file headers must lead back to a main.cpp where you plan to use the function and secondly, you must have the #ifndef and #endif macro in very header file. The last problem that I see is that you must aslo

Header files will not accept functions of each other if you don't add the include "header file"

Solution:

Add include "header file" in the files that need functions from that header file. Or create child and parent class so it makes it easier to "connect" them and use their functions together.

Q : Aslo, Why not put all your header files in to the same header file?

Comment: To answer both of you @karol/@bot, I have if ifndef, define and endif in place. and my header files are all connected.
My tutor has looked through it several times so it is unlikely to be basic issues with the code. He has also copied the code I have written and pasted it into a mew project and it runs fine.
(It wont compile because it is incomplete code, but the errors I am experiencing are not there)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using this structure for every header file:

```
#ifndef FILENAME_H
#define FILENAME_H

//Code here

#endif
```

Remember that `FILENAME_H` needs to be unique for every file.
This will prevent looping of includes in your files.

Comment: see above for an answer to your query